# replacing special characters using sed command

Tags: sed

I have a file fooap.p and I am using sed command to get the output like fooap.

```
echo fooap.p | sed s/\.\p//g
```

but the output I am getting is just foo.

Am I missing something?

Comment: you're using sed on the file *name*? In order to rename it, or to do something else?

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to quote the pattern for `sed`. Then, you need to escape the dot, so that it's treated literally. Thus, try this:

```
echo fooap.p | sed 's/\.p//'
```

The last `g` in your code is superfluous.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/\.p$/p/' /path/to/input
```